# Embedding of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$, char$F=2$, such that $x$ do not remain nilpotent

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

If $L$ is a semi-simple linear Lie algebra inside $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ then for any element of $L$, the Jordan decomposition (semi-simple + nilpotent) inside $L$ and in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ coincide.

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field, but of characteristic $2$. Then $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ is **not** semi-simple.

**Qeustion:** Can we embed $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ in some $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ so  that $x=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ *does not remain* nilpotent in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$?

---

**Assumptions:** All vector space, representation spaces are finite dimensional, $F$ is algebraically closed,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ in characteristic $2$, with basis $(x,y,z)$, has
Lie bracket $[x,y]=z$, so is just the usual Heisenberg Lie algebra. Certainly the Heisenberg Lie algebra has a representation $\rho$ such that $\rho(x)$ is not nilpotent; just take the [standard faithful representation of dimension $3$](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg-Algebra) and add the identity on the diagonal for the representing operator of $x$, i.e., 
$$
\rho(x)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\;
\rho(y)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
\rho(z)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$